# pandas conditional logic with mixed dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
foo bar
a   b
1   10
2   25
3   9
```

I want to add a new column as follows:

```
foo bar baz
a   b   0
1   10  1
2   25  1
3   9   1
```

Which is:
if row['foo'] or row['bar] is numeric, then row['baz'] = 1 else 0

What I have so far is:

```
def some_function(row):
   if row['foo']>=0 or row['bar']>=0:
      return 1
   return 0

df['baz'] = df.apply(lambda row: some_function(row), axis=1
```

But this doesn't work because the dtype is not `int`.
I can't drop `non-int` rows, because I need them in the dataframe.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If want check numeric saved as strings use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stble/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), then compare with `ge` (`>=`) and use [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all values are `True` per rows:

```
df['baz'] = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').ge(0).all(1).astype(int)
print (df)
  foo bar  baz
0   a   b    0
1   1  10    1
2   2  25    1
3   3   9    1
```

Or if need check columns separately:

```
df['baz'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['foo'], errors='coerce').ge(0) | 
            pd.to_numeric(df['bar'], errors='coerce').ge(0)).astype(int)
```

Thanks, Zero for solution for check numeric:

```
df['baz'] = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='force').notnull().all(1).astype(int)
```

---

But if numeric with strings is necessary compare `type`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['a', 1, 2, 3], 'bar': ['b', 10, 25, 9]}) 


df['baz'] = (df.applymap(type) == str).all(1).astype(int)
print (df)
  bar foo  baz
0   b   a    1
1  10   1    0
2  25   2    0
3   9   3    0
```

Detail:

```
print (df.applymap(type))
             bar            foo
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
2  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
3  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Need `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='force').notnull().all(1).astype(int)` perhaps.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks! Any idea how I can check if the value in 'foo' or 'bar' is >= 5? and apply the above condition?

Comment: Change `ge(5)` - `greater or equal`

Comment: You're a star! thanks! @Zero thanks for your suggestion too :)

Comment: I'm curious; does `apply` run at ~the same speed as a python `for` loop in this case (i.e. not vectorized)? I was under the impression that `apply` does, but cant test atm.

Comment: If want faster solution the best is compare each column separately, `apply` is `loop in pandas`, so it should be slowier as native pandas function. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316) is nice comaprision of pandas aproaches.

Comment: Thats a nice link, thanks. The main thing I was thinking when back at a PC was to test if you could vectorize the check over the two columns separately for speed. I guess `apply` wins for readability here :)